# Cannot log in to Visual Studio Account in VS 2022

Tags: azure, visual-studio

When click the login button on visual studio, I am presented with an error and then VS becomes totally unresponsive:

[image: trying to login]

The error reads as follows

```
We could not add the account
Unknown Status: Unexpected
Error: 0xffffffff80070520
Context: Unexpected exception while waiting for accounts control to finish:
        'A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.'
Tag: 0x1f7d734b (error code -2147023584) (internal error code 528315211)
```

We use TFS to do our source control, but searching online for solutions, this error always seems to be associated with Git (or maybe it's just more popular?), so solutions mention the GCM credential helper that is an option with Git, but does not apply to TFS.

I can't access the TFS server through VS either - when I first open it up, I see this message in the output window:

```
TF205020: Could not connect to server ‘[server]’. This server was used in your last session, but it might be offline or unreachable.
Confirm that the server is available on the network. To attempt to connect again, or to a different server, click ‘Connect To Azure DevOps Server’ in Team Explorer or the Team menu.

The server returned the following error: TF30063: You are not authorized to access [server].
```

I was able to confirm that the TFS server is available on the network; I can log in and access it in my browser using the same account. I clicked `Help->My Subscription->Benifits` and when that opened up in the browser, I could log in fine there as well.

Yesterday afternoon, the account that I am using was locked out of Windows, but it was reinstated in Active Directory - This is the first time I am logging into VS since then, which seems like strong circumstancial evidence for the cause of the problem!

How can I log in?

EDIT - Adding additional info:

I uninstalled Visual Studio 2022, then reinstalled and got the logon window as part of my first time opening the newly installed application, but the same error appeared.

[image: New Installation, same Error]

Comment: Did you try logging with any other accounts?

Comment: I don't even get the opportunity - as soon as I click the Sign In button, I get the error and the program becomes entirely unresponsive to all interaction.

Comment: Same thing just started happening on my machine. My account has never been locked out.

Comment: Exact same error started today on my VS2022, cant sign in. Running VS2022 normally (ie; double click and run) can sign into accounts.
But I need to run with elevated access or as using Run as using a different domain user. 

This was working till few hours back and now I cant sign in so cant restore nuget packages from domain and if I try it hangs.

Have tried, deleting AppDate\Local\.IdentityService folder.
Reset the VS2022 settings using VS command prompt.
Update the VS2022 version to the the latest one.
repaired the installation 

Nothing has worked.

Comment: A suggestion, if title could be, cant login into VS 2022, and not really cant login into azure. 
This seems more a VS issue as the login screen is not presented.

Comment: @user2647784 - good point; done.

Comment: @user2647784 I, too, am running Visual Studio as a different user to the one that is logged onto my machine (I have an "admin" account with elevated permissions). I am logged onto the machine as the same user that has the Microsoft account. I don't know whether this is coincidence or relevant; it's never been a problem before.

Comment: I doubt its a coincidence, at least 3 individuals have the same error as per comments here, while running VS 2022 with a user requiring elevated access.

Comment: It seems to have resolved for me... only by luck.
Steps followed
Link: https://superuser.com/questions/1706179/visual-studio-2022-stuck-in-authorization-loop

I tried this
In the "Account Settings" window click "Account options", change the drop-down for "Add and reauthenticate account using:" from "Embedded web browser" to "System web browser".

but it did not open the browser after few attempts, so put the setting back to Embedded.

Tried login again and it worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]It seems to have resolved for me... only by luck. Steps followed Link: [Click here](https://superuser.com/questions/1706179/visual-studio-2022-stuck-in-authorization-loop) I tried this In the "Account Settings" window click "Account options", change the drop-down for "Add and reauthenticate account using:" from "Embedded web browser" to "System web browser". but it did not open the browser after few attempts, so put the setting back to Embedded. Tried login again and it worked.

Open VS 2022 -> Tools (at the very top) -> Options , search for connect, see under Environment -> accounts , then follow rest of the steps as above

Comment: Yes, you saved my day. I'm also running VS2022 with another (higher privileged) account than the one I'm logged into Windows with. I think the embedded browser doesn't play nice with that, and for me the problems started this morning when I updated to VS 2022 17.7.5 so maybe something changed with the update

Comment: yes, for me it also started yesterday. Same logged into the laptop with one user and running VS 2022 with another user.

Comment: I don't get the Account Settings option because I have not yet logged in - unless, is that window accessible any other than on the top right of VS where your login name is displayed?

Comment: This worked for me :). Changed it to system browser, clicked on the top right signin button and then it opened in edge to signin. After that everything is back to normal :) thx

Comment: Yes, this worked - File -> Account Settings and then follow instructions in the answer. I was able to login using the `System Web Browser`. Once logged in, I could log in and out freely, even with the setting returned to `Embedded Web Browser`.

Comment: Good, it worked for me also!

Answer (score 4):

This error is seen when visual studio is being run as a different user than who is signed into the windows session.

A recent change was made to prefer using the windows authentication broker over other authentication mechanisms in visual studio such as the embedded browser or system browser.

One problem with this is that the RunAs scenario does not work with the windows authentication broker.

If you need to runas another user then you will need to turn off the windows broker before signing in.
To do this, you can go to File->AccountSettings->AccountOptions , then change the dropdown on the right hand side to another option other than "Windows Authentication broker"

This currently is an issue with the broker flow, and if possible, we would like anyone else encountering this issue to upvote this feedback ticket https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/We-could-not-add-the-account-Unknown-St/10488678. A comment on why VS is being run as a different user would also help us understand and communicate with our partner teams who own the implementation why this scenario is important.    The currently known use case is to be signed in as a non admin user and have to run visual studio as a different user for security reasons.

Comment: I added a comment as you suggested to the MS Ticket (it is too long to include in the comments here but can be seen by following the link in your answer)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach worked for me (was suggested by one of my coworkers). It works when you usually login on your computer with a non-admin account, but you run VS 2022 as admin.

Login into Windows with the admin account. Start VS 2022 as admin, sign in. Close VS 2022, logoff. Login into Windows with the non-admin account.

Comment: I need to get clearance from the security guys to use my admin account to log in, but will try this.

Comment: Sadly this is a no-go solution for me as apparently there are security considerations that mean it is bad practice for my admin user to log into a machine (not sure what they are, but I am disallowed from trying this approach).